# Is Sefer HaRazim heretical?

Tags: jewish-books, heresy, practical-kabbalah

Is the book [Sefer HaRazim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sefer_HaRazim) heretical?

Does it play any part in kabbalah? If so, is it still used by kabbalists today?

Comment: Is the combination of these questions a sly way of asking whether kabbalah is heretical?

Comment: @magicker72 I'm aware that Sefer Harazim specifically is considered by some to be questionable, so I don't see any reason to view this as a jab at kabbalah in general.

Comment: @Harel13 well if they're hoping the three questions here have the answer 'yes', then it would seem to say something about their view of kabbalah

Comment: As with many things, there are likely some who consider it heretical, some who consider it fundamental. some who consider it neutral, and some who are indifferent.

Comment: Have you ever read it? It's mostly angels names, purpose, hierarchy and background of the translated texts. Buy it and learn it, then question.

Comment: @magicker72 Not at all. In fact, I have nothing against kabbalah. The reason I ask whether it is heretical is because, having read it, there are passages where one calls out to Angels rather than to God, which is problematic, is it not?

Comment: @TwoOs Yes, I have read it, and I found some aspects of it to be problematic, hence my question.

Comment: What seems problematic ?

Comment: @Temporary It's worth explaining that in your question so answerers can address your concerns more directly.

Comment: Could you write where in the book are those passages you're referring to?

Answer (score 1):

Rabbi Avigdor Shiloh wrote in [this](https://www.kipa.co.il/%D7%A9%D7%90%D7%9C-%D7%90%D7%AA-%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%91/%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8-%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%96%D7%99%D7%9D/) Q&A that in general, there aren't discrepancies between the Talmud and Sefer Harazim, although some of the things outlined there are no longer applicable per halacha.

[Mordechai Margulies](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%93%D7%9B%D7%99_%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%92%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%95%D7%AA), in his edition of the book, wrote that historically, the book is known to have been used by rabbis in the time of the Gaonim, because some of the Karaites (such as [Daniel Al-Kumisi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniel_al-Kumisi) and [Yaakov Al-Kirkisani](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacob_Qirqisani)) criticized these rabbis for using books such as this one (pg. XII). Furthermore, [Rabbi Elazar of Worms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eleazar_of_Worms) quoted the book extensively in his book Sodei Razaya, although he only quoted the more theoretical parts and not the acts and oaths and the names of angels (those found solely in Harazim) (pg. XIV). Books that may have been based off of Sefer Harazim include: [Charba D'Moshe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sword_of_Moses), Sefer Adam, Sefer Hamalbush, [Sodei Razaya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eleazar_of_Worms#Pietistic_works), [Sefer Raziel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sefer_Raziel_HaMalakh).

I don't personally know any kabbalists (at least, not that I'm aware of), but I'd guess that like the Roke'ach (Rabbi Elazar of Worms), if the book is still in use today, it's the theoretical portions that are used.